# How to convert encoded url from upper cases to lower cases

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I convert Link like that

```
http://localhost:50492/%D8%A3%D8%AD%D8%AF%D8%AB-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%82-%D8%B2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%B1
```

to be lower case like that

```
https://www.drahmedmekkawy.com/%d8%a3%d8%ad%d8%af%d8%ab-%d8%b7%d8%b1%d9%82-%d8%b2%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%b9%d8%a9-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b4%d8%b9%d8%b1
```

the URL is originally look like this
http://localhost:50492/أحدث-طرق-زراعة-الشعر

This is my `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
    
    bool found = false;
    string URL = String.Empty;

    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("cpanel") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains(".axd") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("localhost"))
    {
        if (!builder.Host.Contains("www"))
        {
            builder.Host = "www." + builder.Host;
            found = true;
        }

        URL = builder.ToString();
        URL = Server.UrlDecode(URL);

        // Convert URL to lowercase
        URL = URL.ToLower();

        // Re-encode the URL
        URL = Server.UrlEncode(URL);
    }
}
```

The encoding is happening because the Url is in arabic. But I want to make the encoding from upper case to lower case is it available and can I do that ?

I want to be global on the whole website I also tried to create a module

```
/    public class LowercaseUrlModule : IHttpModule
//    {
//        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
//        {
//            context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
//        }

//        public void Dispose() { }

//        private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
//        {
//            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
//            HttpContext context = application.Context;

//            string lowercaseUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower();

//            if (!string.Equals(context.Request.RawUrl, lowercaseUrl, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
//            {
//                // If the URL has changed to lowercase, perform a redirect
//                context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
//                context.Response.AddHeader("Location", lowercaseUrl);
//                context.Response.End();
//            }
//        }
//    }
//}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-7.0#system-string-tolower(system-globalization-cultureinfo)